# Performant way to check items in array exist in another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that contain numbers representing IDs.  I need to remove all numbers from the first array that don't appear in the second array.

This is how I am doing it:

```
$array1 = PopulateArray1();
$array2 = PopulateArray2();

$matchedRows = array();

foreach ($array1 as $item)
{
    if(in_array($item, $array2))
    {
        $matchedRows[] = $item;
    }
}

return $matchedRows;
```

It could be likely that the arrays will get fairly large so I am wondering if this is the best way to do this or if there is a way with better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$matchedRows = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```